# Select statement on XML not returning desired output

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
DECLARE @barcode XML

            SET @barcode = '<BCODES><BCODE>a</BCODE><BCODE>b</BCODE><BCODE>c</BCODE><BCODE>d</BCODE></BCODES>'

            --INSERT INTO #barcode
            SELECT      v.x.value('BCODE[1]','VARCHAR(15)') AS Barcodes
            FROM        @barcode.nodes('BCODES') v(x)
```

Result-->

### Barcodes

a

I'm unable to get b,c and d in the output.

Comment: To clarify: you expect `SELECT` to return `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` but only `a` is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
SELECT v.x.value('.','VARCHAR(15)') AS Barcodes
FROM @barcode.nodes('BCODES/BCODE') v(x)
```

The idea is first to get all `BCODE` nodes and then to extract its values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
DECLARE @barcode XML;
SET @barcode = '<BCODES><BCODE>a</BCODE><BCODE>b</BCODE><BCODE>c</BCODE><BCODE>d</BCODE></BCODES>';

            --INSERT INTO #barcode

SELECT barcode = n.v.value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
FROM @barcode.nodes('BCODES/BCODE') AS n(v);
```

Result :

```
barcode 
a
b
c
d
```